# Is a 'shared calendar' simply a calendar that has been shared with one or more other persons

Tags: office-365, calendar, outlook

Is there such a thing in MS365 as a 'shared calendar' as distinct from a personal calendar or is a shared calendar simply somebody's calendar (probably not their primary one) that has been shared with one or more other people?

Put another way, if I want to create a shared calendar for a group of people do I create it in just the same way as I would a calendar for myself and then share it or is there another process to create a different sort of entity?

Many thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this very much depends on whether the facility is within an **intranet** to the exclusion of anyone outside the organisation or an **extranet** where information can be shared externally such as you would find in general access to the internet with the likes of Google Calendar.

So, in essence, if your need is to reach out to people both within and beyond your organisational structure then the need could be met by using a calendar which allows you to select the people to whom read and/or write access is permitted but to create a shared calendar in Office 365 you need to create a shared mailbox and assign full access permissions to users who will use its calendar. The calendar that comes along with this shared mailbox will become the shared calendar for the selected users.